# How to down vote users that answer questions in the "question comments" section?

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes

I have been seeing a lot of people that come into a question after the fact, and then use the comment section to answer the question. The only purpose of this is so their response appears at the top. I think this type of behavior needs to be discouraged, and the comment section only used for clarifying the questions.

Should we be flagging these comments, or is there a way to impact the people doing this?

And another thing, if someone write a comment as, "**Community Wiki**" that should be an automatic 50 point cost to the author. Then only people with a lot of rep would continue to be Wiki *Politzi*.

**Update:** Guess this is a sore topic. Anyway, why not just have a Community wiki "vote" button and be done with it?

Comment: I was with you until the Community Wiki part...

Comment: I suggest that people who complain about "Wiki Police" should be docked all of their rep. This is fun!

Comment: Community Wiki

Comment: To answer your question, I suppose you *could* flag them, but why bother?  They can't gain any rep by answering in a comment, and the comment *is* on topic.  Are they really causing any harm?

Comment: This question would be so much better, if it didn't have a reference to Community Wiki.

Answer (score 10):

Re wiki: what is the bee in the bonnet that some people have? Some questions genuinely are (IMO) best served as wiki - or at worst deleted. And I fully defend the right of people to suggest that something **should** be a wiki. Otherwise, there is a portion of questions which *while programming related* are clearly intended as a means at rep-garnering. I'm not going to get into whether that is the intended meaning of wiki, but it is what the community has evolved to want and expect.

Frankly, I find terms like "Wiki Politzi" / "wiki police" to be offensive and derogatory to the users who **quite reasonably, and in line with the accepted forum usage** suggest wiki would be appropriate.

If you are seeing lots of "wiki please" comments on your posts... maybe you should think whether the questions you are asking are actually the core aim of the site - i.e. fixing problems, not an open discussion board.

Comment: It is absolutely acceptable behavior to attempt to demonize and name call someone who operates differently from you.

Comment: I say we should take back the term Wiki Police! If there were an application board, I'd enlist.

Comment: @TheTXI - like heck it is, pony-lover! `<g>`

Answer (score 7):

What is it that you are so upset about? Where is the harm when someone answers in a comment? The worst thing that can happen is that the comment section gets a bit cluttered. I also doubt what you said about the motivation of those commentators: "The only purpose of this is so their response appears at the top." You don't get much rep for a comment, even if it contains a perfect answer.

Comment: Indeed; nor does it bump the front page for visibility. Motivation for *general* attention? zero.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question: I think it's better to first add a comment yourself explaining it should be posted as an answer. Only flag the comment (or flag the question for moderator attention) when you don't get any response. Down-voting those people (on other answers/questions for instance) is not a good reaction!

For your 'other thing': **No way**! I actually haven't seen that much of 'community wiki' comments which weren't appropriate.
And... How will the system know it has to charge a 'C0mun1ty VV1k1 plz' comment?

Comment: Hey, flagging a comment is a way to point hate-speech, not breaking SO rules. There is a huge difference between posting communist or fascist comment and answering question in question's comment.

Comment: Flagging is also meant to get 'moderator attention'. But I agree partly, that's why I put 'or add a comment yourself explaining it should be posted as an answer'. Actually, I think it's better to do that first, before getting moderator attention. I'll update my answer...